# Can cookies be created without a domain name?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a function that changes my webpage's theme between different external css style sheets so the user can choose a colour theme for their experience.

I have tried several different ways to try and apply the change to all the pages on my website, at the moment it only changes the current page, when you click to a different page the theme returns to the default setting.

Below is an extract of my code:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="blue.css" id = "blueStyle" title = "blueStyle" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="red.css" id = "redStyle" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type = "text/css" href="green.css" id = "greenStyle" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function setStyleSheet(url) {
            var stylesheet = document.getElementById("blueStyle");
            stylesheet.setAttribute('href', url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="styleRed" onclick = "setStyleSheet('red.css')" href = "red.css">Red Theme</div>
    <div id ="styleGreen" onclick = "setStyleSheet('green.css')" href = "green.css">Green Theme</div>
    <div id ="styleBlue" onclick = "setStyleSheet('blue.css')" href = "blue.css">Blue Theme</div>
</body>
```

The code and functions work fine and all colours change on the current page when I run it but as soon as you click to another page the default colour returns.

I know I should use cookies to store this data in, but this is my first project and I am only just starting to learn cookies. The issue is I only have this project on Notepad++ which is a text editor.

I do not have a web host or a domain name yet but is there a way to test the cookies to see if the functions work if the site is only in the development stage? Or MUST I have a domain name assigned to the cookie to test it?

Comment: Chrome does not accept cookies on local files (e.g. using the `file:///` protocol instead of `http://`). Firefox and IE do, so you can test on those. The proper way would be to install a local server (a server running on your machine, which you can access using `http://localhost/`). Check out WAMP if you're on Windows or MAMP if you're on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

A domain is not the requirement, HTTP(S) is. Cookies are an HTTP State Management Mechanism as defined in [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265). As such, the browser needs to be loading the files via HTTP(S) in order for cookie interaction to take place.

The only way to work locally and use cookies is to run a web server locally such that you can load the files with the `http://` scheme as opposed to the `file://` scheme.

Depending on the configuration of the web server, you could then load the pages via `http://localhost`, `http://127.0.0.1`, `http://x.x.x.x` (where `x.x.x.x` is an IP on one of your machines interfaces), or via some locally pointed fake domain name (via `/etc/hosts`).

Some pre-built server packages for getting your feet wet are:

- [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
- [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com)
- [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info)

I know that if you pay for MAMP Pro, it comes with a tool for helping create local domain names (it edits `/etc/hosts` for you). I don't know if the others offer things like this.

Comment: Just to emphasize, you DON'T need a domain name to test if cookies work, a web server on your local machine (127.0.0.1 known as localhost ) will suffice.

If you plan to host the files somewhere else such as a web server or another computer on your local network, you can use the IP of that machine (public one for the remote web server and LAN IP for the computer on the LAN).

Comment: Agreed. Claritifcation added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fake domain name to test it by changing your host file. Open up C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts with a notepad and add the following line at the end

```
127.0.0.1       www.myfakedomain.com
```

and then you can just navigate to `www.myfakedomain.com` to see your website on your local machine. Which then you can set the cookie's domain to that and test it.

Comment: Your local machine will, of course, need to be running an HTTP server.

Comment: This answer is lacking the obvious pre-requisite of having a server set up on your local machine.

Comment: I thought he meant that cookie doesn't recognize localhost as a domain.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above solutions are great, however they are more complicated. Another simple solution is to use the querystring to pass the style. The below basic code:

_get is a simple function to grab the querystring

I modified your set style to loop through all links and add style= to all of the links on the page to pass the style to other files.

If this was a production project, I wouldn't recommend this but as it isn't, this could work for you.

```
    <html>
<head>
<head>
<body>


<script>
function _get(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

     function setStyleSheet(url) {
            var stylesheet = document.getElementById("blueStyle");
            stylesheet.setAttribute('href', url);

            $("a").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href") + "?style=" + url);
            });
        }

        if(_get("style") != null){
        console.log("style is " + _get("style"));
        }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This gives a way for the OP to persist across requests, but doesn't really help a returning user. Moreover, the largest part of the OP's question (for which you have provided this solution) is just a use case for the actual question. The actual question is whether or not cookies need a domain, and this answer does not address that question.